# SimpleSeedProvider.java:62 - Seed provider couldn't lookup host cass1, using docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am trying to run two/three cassandra docker image instances on same device & want to make cluster from these.

Using windows & docker desktop. Same result when I have tried on WSL2 Ubuntu.

I have followed instructions to make cluster on same machine from https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra

1. Pulled latest cassandra image from docker hub.
2. Run first container with below command

   ```
   docker run --name cass1 -v C:\Learnings\datastax\node1:/var/lib/cassandra -d cassandra
   ```
3. Run second container providing ***CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cass1*** container name to make cluster of two cassandra nodes.
   This container stopped within few seconds after start.

   ```
   docker run --name cass2 -v C:\Learnings\datastax\node2:/var/lib/cassandra -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cass1 -d cassandra
   ```
4. Got the following error in `cass2` logs, when checked using `docker logs cass2`

   ```
   INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2023-10-02 07:22:00,821 StreamManager.java:260 - Storing streaming state for 3d or for 119156 elements
   WARN  [main] 2023-10-02 07:22:05,950 SimpleSeedProvider.java:62 - Seed provider couldn't lookup host cass1
   Exception (org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException) encountered during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds.
   The seed provider lists no seeds.
   ERROR [main] 2023-10-02 07:22:05,954 CassandraDaemon.java:897 - Exception encountered during startup: The seed provider lists no seeds.
   ```